# support for converting the tuples to elements in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation which contains 7 fields and want to convert into below output.

Input :

```
(x,y,10,z,20,a,30) ->(chararray,chararray,double,chararray,double,chararray,double)
```

Output should be like below..

```
(x,y,10)
(x,z,20)
(x,a,30)
```

Could you please let any one know how to achieve this.....

Comment: Welcome to SO - if you want to get real help, share as much information and what you have tried till now. So - please share what is the logic of the split, also what have you tried til now. did you consider using UDF that take tuple and return bag ?

Comment: i dont want to use UDF ..i have tried doing converting into Bag but i didnt find required results...

Comment: can you share what have you tried ? also share the logic - if it fix for all records ?  if yes - read this https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#relations

Comment: B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));

Answer (score 1):

You have used the right function TOBAG.TOBAG(*) means apply TOBAG on all fields. CONCAT the fields that needs to be converted to rows and then FLATTEN the concatenated fields.

Note:You are using double for few fields,so you will see decimal precision with the fields that are loaded as double.

```
A = LOAD 'test7.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:double,f4:chararray,f5:double,f6:chararray,f7:double);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,FLATTEN(TOBAG(CONCAT(f2,CONCAT(',',(chararray)f3)),CONCAT(f4,CONCAT(',',(chararray)f5)),CONCAT(f6,CONCAT(',',(chararray)f7))));
DUMP B;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks .However this gives the (y,10.0) as chararray.Here i want this to be two fields and they are chararray(y) and doulbe(10.0).Because i want to filter the values based on some condition.

Comment: @Devndra Add another step to cast the fields to datatype of your choice.C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,$1,(double)$2;